# How to ignore specific directories while reading an s3 prefix using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read below s3 URI
*s3://data/bronze/dc/daily/spapi_unsuppressed_inventories/*

and I want to ignore the backup folder while reading from the prefix:
*s3://data/bronze/dc/daily/spapi_unsuppressed_inventories/report_date=20220809
s3://data/bronze/dc/daily/spapi_unsuppressed_inventories/report_date=20220810
s3://data/bronze/dc/daily/spapi_unsuppressed_inventories/backup*

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://data/bronze/dc/daily/spapi_unsuppressed_inventories/report_date=*")
```

You can read more about globs [here](https://hail.is/docs/0.2/hadoop_glob_patterns.html).